# emberjs findRecord is not implemented

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I try to use the Restadapter from emberjs to call my api under 'http://local.ember.api' but I can't get any data. After some respearch I didn't get it working. Here is my code:

I created a file under app/application with the name adapter.js with this code:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import $ from 'jquery';
import config from '../config/environment';

var ApplicationAdapter;
ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://local.ember.api',
    namespace: 'api/v1'
});

var ApplicationSerializer;
ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({});

export default ApplicationAdapter;
export default ApplicationSerializer;
```

and under app/models I have a user.js with this code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

var User = DS.Model.extend({});

export default User;
```

my app/router.js looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('users');
  this.route('user', {path: '/user/:user_id'});
});

export default Router;
```

and my app/routes/user.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
  }
});
```

with this setup I get this error:

```
Error: Assertion Failed: You tried to find a record but your adapter (for test-app@model:user:) does not implement 'findRecord'
```

when I create a file under app/services with the name store.js and this code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Store;
Store = DS.Store.extend({});

export default Store;
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Assertion Failed: You tried to find a record but your adapter (for test-app@model:user:) does not implement 'findRecord'
```

when I create a function with the name 'findRecord' in the store.js-File:

```
Store = DS.Store.extend({
    findRecord: function() {}
});
```

I get no result. Where is the mistake?

Comment: What version of Ember Data (and Ember) are you using?

Comment: I use Ember: 1.13.10 and Ember Data : 1.13.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are calling `find` on the Store, but the according to the [documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_findRecord) you should be calling `findRecord` as there is no `find`. Hence, the error message.

When you create the `findRecord` method, it's probably being called but since you don't return anything... well you don't get any data back. If you `console.log` there, it's probably being called.

Edit:
I found the line where that error happens in ember-data's [source code](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/7f341674455776eac3992bd29274bd84ae599655/addon/system/store.js#L602) (although it's from master). But looking at the source code form 1.13.15 it should have the `find` method and it should give you a [warning](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/0f0a9b061fa762bbb4aa8aca218d5e67a4c2d31f/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest-adapter.js#L370-L375).

Can you setup an [EmberTwiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I didn't get it working on EmberTwiddle. Can we discuss this on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95670/room-for-pedro-rio-and-evolutio